# Error when using Redis with C# : value is not an integer or out of range, sPort: 51410, LastCommand:

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, redis, servicestack.redis

The following code below sets a key in redis with an expiry period if it does not exist and increments its value everytime if the key already exists, the code gives an exception when i try to increment the existing value of a key, that is when it enters the **'If'** block

**Exception message :** value is not an integer or out of range, sPort: 51814, LastCommand:

```
public bool SetKeyInRedis(string Id, double Amount)
    {
        bool b = false;

        try
        {
            string Key = "Id:" + Id;
            using (var redisClient = new RedisClient(RedisIPAddress,RedisPortNo))
            {
                if (redisClient.Exists(Key) == 1)
                {
                    redisClient.IncrByFloat(Key, Amount);
                    b = true;
                }
                else if (redisClient.Exists(Key) == 0)
                {
                    DateTime Today = DateTime.Now;
                    DateTime EndOfMonth = new DateTime(Today.Year, Today.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(Today.Year, Today.Month));

                    b = redisClient.Set<double>(Key, Amount, EndOfMonth);
                }
                else
                {
                    //to-do
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message);
        }

        return b;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Figured out the solution:**

I was using the older version of all the required [ServiceStack dll's for Redis](https://servicestack.net/redis), downloaded the new versions of all the required dll's and it works flawlessly now.

Answer (score 0):

[INCRBYFLOAT](http://redis.io/commands/INCRBYFLOAT) expects the increment to be a float, not a double.

Pass `float amount` , instead of `double amount`as double might not be supported by this command.

Comment: I tried changing the data type to float , but still i am facing the same issue.